# Difference between 点 and 要素?

Tags: word-choice

I understand that they both mean "element" or "aspect" in some way. What's the nuanced difference between the two?

Answer (score 2):

点 merely implies a "point", while 要素 implies there are multiple points that together make up something.

Hence, you can say `昨日来てくれた点は評価する`, but not `昨日来てくれた要素は評価する` because you coming over is odd as a component of something. Conversely, you can say `成長を促す要素を構成している` but not `成長を促す点を構成している` because a point can't be composed of further components.